# Can a non-abelian subgroup be such that the right cosets equal the left cosets?

Tags: group-theory

So, I know that every abelian (commutative) group $G$ is such that, for any subgroup $H$, the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ are the right cosets. I guess this is true even if $G$ is not abelian, but $H$ is (but I'm not sure). Is this enough to characterise the subgroup as abelian, or are there examples of non-abelian subgroups with this property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a subgroup of a group, the condition of being abelian is neither necessary nor sufficient for being [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup):

If $G$ is non-abelian, then $H=G$ is a normal but non-abelian subgroup. As another example, the [alternating group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) is a normal but non-abelian subgroup of the symmetric group.

For a counterexample in the converse direction, consider the [free group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) with two generators. The subgroup generated by one of the generators is abelian (isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$) but not normal. (This means that your guess above is wrong.)

Comment: I would have given a smaller example of "abnormal" abelian subgoups, like the order 2 subgroups of S_3.

Answer (score 10):

The left cosets of $H$ are the same as the right cosets
of $H$ if and only if $H$ is a [normal subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) of $G$.
There are non-abelian groups all subgroups of which are normal,
for example the quaternion group of order $8$.

Comment: They are called "Hamiltonian groups": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group

Comment: @Robin, the "if" direction is obvious, but (at least to me) the "only if" is not.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan: $gH=Hg\Leftrightarrow gHg^{-1}=H$

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard: yes, that shows the "if" direction.  My interpretation of the left cosets being "equal" to the right cosets is that they determine the same partition of G, and I do not see how this argument addresses the "only if" direction.

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan: If $H$ is not normal, there is a $g$ such that $gHg^{-1}\not=H$, and thus $gH\not=Hg$, and the partitions differ.

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard: I do not understand why Hg must be the right coset which is the same as gH.  To say this another way, I do not understand why this rules out the existence of a nonidentity function a : G \to G such that g H = H a(g).

Comment: Consider the partition given by the gH. Then gH is THE member of the partition containing g. (Similarly for the other partition.)

Comment: Thanks; that's what I was missing.

Comment: The question was whether abelian subgroups are normal, not whether non-abelian groups can have all subgroups normal. This is not an answer.