# If G is not commutative, then is there always a subgroup that is not a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was having a discussion with a friend of mine about some normal group properties and then came up with the question "if G is not commutative, then is there always a subgroup that is not a normal subgroup?" It's probably more easy to solve this in the following form:$$\forall H \leq G : H  \lhd G \Rightarrow \forall a,b \in G : ab=ba$$
My question is, can anybody give a proof, or a counter-example (because I don't think it holds) of this theorem? Thanks!

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of the following one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/help-on-subgroup-and-normal-subgroup.

Comment: @Pete: Good catch; but I think the question is stated better here, so maybe we should close the other one as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: See also this question: [Can a non-abelian subgroup be such that the right cosets equal the left cosets?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/can-a-non-abelian-subgroup-be-such-that-the-right-cosets-equal-the-left-cosets), and especially this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/can-a-non-abelian-subgroup-be-such-that-the-right-cosets-equal-the-left-cosets/3601#3601) (by Robin Chapman), and the comments.

Comment: @Zev: sure, what you suggest sounds quite reasonable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer is no.  The [Quaternion Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) provides the smallest counter example.

Another way to write your question is the following: "Does there exist a non Abelian group all whose subgroups are normal."  Such counter examples to your above conjecture actually have a specific name, and can be completely classified.   These are called [Hamiltonian Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_group).

Comment: thank you for the nice counterexample!